# Can I use the React Router < Router /> component with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

If I wanted to use the React Router `<Router />` component with `create-react-app`, am I able to do so without ejecting? I noticed that the React Router example page uses `<Switch>`, and it looks like `<Router />` is contained within `ReactDOM.render` (which create-react-app places inside of the Index.JS entry point file).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to eject your create-react-app to you use React Router. Just install it alongside as an NPM package and import it just like normal. It will not conflict with any of the default React implementation.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if I could specifically use <Router>. I'm confused because <Route> is used within ReactDOM.render, which, with create-react-app, is placed inside of the index.js file.

Comment: @ChrisClark I'm not sure what you mean? I wouldn't be worried about the use of <Route> within the internal render method of React. That shouldn't affect the usage or <Router> throughout the rest of your application.